# No mod_php? 14.04 / ondrej php5.6 + ondrej apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04, php-5.6, mod-php

Trying to get a 14.04 box running PHP 5.6, but having issues getting PHP enabled in apache. Specifically, it doesn't seem mod_php is being installed anymore?

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-software-properties
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y

apt-get install -y htop apache2 php5.6 php5.6-curl php5.6-mcrypt mongodb-org curl git
```

`a2enmod` does not list `php` or `mod_php`, and `locate php.ini` outputs:

```
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/5.6/php.ini-production.cli
```

However including a `<?php phpinfo();` in an `index.php` served by apache is not processed.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TLDR

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

### Long Answer

So I found the solution, which although simple, is not as intuitive as the official php packages.

After adding the apache2 and php PPA's, and installing all the packages, one needs to manually install the `libapache2-mod-php5.6` package as well, which adds the `php5.6` apache2 module. The confusion is that the default ubuntu php5 packages include this package as part of the install, however the ones from ondrej's PPA do not.

In case anyone wants to know or cares, I was able to solve this by searching through the closed issues on his github repo which is meant to track issues with his PPA's: [Issue #266](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/266) gave me the clue.