# How to force Apache use the latest installed PHP version

Tags: php, apache

I have upgrade from PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 to PHP 5.6.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 using these commands:

```
apt-get -y update
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl
```

But I have problem with versions:

```
php -v
```

outputs:

```
PHP 5.6.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

And

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

outputs:

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
```

How can I force Apache use the latest php (in my case PHP 5.6.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2) version?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I did

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172436/no-mod-php-14-04-ondrej-php5-6-ondrej-apache2

Comment: Pretty sure you want `libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: @AbraCadaver libapache2-mod-php5.6 is installed, but phpinfo() still displays old one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I was able to solve my problem:

```
#Disable php5 mod
a2dismod php5

#Enable php5.6 mod
a2enmod php5.6

#restart apache2
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: for php8.1 i had to manually install the module cause it was missing on my local machine by  ```sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.1```
then you'll be able to execute  ```sudo a2enmod php8.1``` then restart your apache server with `service apache2 restart`