# CLI running PHP 7.1 but Apache 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running a local Vagrant VM which had PHP 7.0 out of the box. I've updated this to PHP 7.1 a while ago.

Now I've noticed that only the CLI is running PHP 7.1. But when I run the webserver (Apache), it is still running PHP 7.0

`phpinfo()` is showing me this

[image]

`$php -v` show this:

```
PHP 7.1.17-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May  5 2018 04:55:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.17-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`, the `php7.1.conf` and `php7.1.load` are enabled. Mods `php7.0.*` are not available.

How can I update my Apache to 7.1.17 as well?

Comment: This may help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084246/how-to-force-apache-use-the-latest-installed-php-version

Comment: @RyanKozak, already tried, but no success.

Comment: Uninstall php7.0.

Comment: root> `which php`?